# nil class when searching tags

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I had a method with the following line

```
@noticias = Noticia.where(:tags.all => array).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

it happens that `brakeman` says that it has a possible sql injection.
I tried the following instead:

```
 array = params[:query].split(' ')
    array.each_with_index  do |query, index|
      array[index] = array[index].gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "").downcase
    end


    array.each do |tag|
      @noticias << Noticia.where(:tags => tag)
    end
```

but i got something like `undefined << for nil:NilClass
what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mongodb, you can sure that your code is SQL Injection free.

> Although MongoDB isn't vulnerable to anything like SQL-injection, it may be worth checking the search string for anything malicious.
>   [mongodb tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html)

Comment: that is what I thought, but what about the error? whats wrong with my code?